# Perl's strange source code

Tags: perl

i did find non alphanumeric perl code that run normaly !
the begin of the code:

```
eval eval '"'.
('!'^'+').'#'.('`'^'!').('['^'.').('['^'/').('`'|'(').('`'|'/').('['^')').':'.('{'^'/').('['^"\,").(
'`'|'%').('`'|'.').('['^'/').('['^'"').('`'^'/').('`'|'.').('`'|'%').('!'^'+').'#'.('`'^'$').(('`')|
'!').('['^'/').('`'|'%').':'.('`'^'!').('['^'.').('`'|"'").('['^'.').('['^'(').('['^'/').('{'^'[')
```

and [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=XERU6EwC)'s the file in pastebin. so how does that happen :D

Comment: That's rather pretty, really, isn't it? The basic trick seems to be using bitwise operations on one character strings to generate other characters, though knowing Perl, there's probably a second layer of obfuscation underneath. Perl has a long history of playing with this kind of thing, I guess because of its strong support for string manipulation and run-time configuration of the language itself.

Comment: Someone had far too much time on their hands when they wrote (generated?) that 'code'.  The `'"'.('!'^'+')` that starts the punctational horror story combines a double quote and another character (a newline), and the incantations continue to generate a string, which is evaluated to generate another string, which is evaluated as a program.

Comment: @user2676847 For future reference: Because SO is intended to feature Q&A format questions that are actually about specific programming problems, and because questions have to clearly state what they're asking, it seems enough people have voted to close this post as is required to put it "on hold".  In the future you might try PerlMonks; the format there is a little different, and what is accepted as a post at PerlMonks often does include topics that lead to discussion instead of the concise Q&A preferred by SO.

Comment: I like how the date in the pastebin code is 1969. That guy was way faster than TimToady. :D

Comment: @DavidO thanks i'll keep that in mind :-)
and many thanks for every one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice the double string eval.  The right-most eval interprets all of the `("["^"/")` type of snippets and concatenates them together.  The left-most eval runs the string that results from the right-most eval's interpretation.

The little (....) snippets each (mostly) take one character and perform bitwise operations such as `xor` and `or` with another character.  So, for example, `("["^"/")` becomes the single character 't'.  This combined with the concatenation builds up a string that is actual runnable Perl code (and that would look a lot more sensible if you unraveled the first (right-most) eval).  And in fact, it's really quite easy to see what the real code looks like.  Simply replace the left-most '`eval`' with a '`print`', and you will see how the right-most `eval` transforms the code.

Here is the output:

```
#Author:TwentyOne
#Date:August 21, 1969
#Title:md5bf.pl
#Description:Generates MD5 checksums provided by brute_keyword and then testing itself against the supplied hashster
#Contact <<<<<removed in SO post>>>>>
$speed = "1";

if ($speed<=0)
{ 
die "Set the speed equal or greater than one.\n";
}

use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);

if ($ARGV[0] =~"new") {
system('clear');
print "Enter a string\n";
print ">";
chomp(my $ask = <STDIN>);
system('clear');
system("echo -n '$ask' | md5sum\n");
exit(1);
}

if ($ARGV[0]=~"l") {
 $brute = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";}
if ($ARGV[0]=~"u") {
 $brute = $brute. "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";}
if ($ARGV[0]=~"n") {
 $brute = $brute."1234567890";}
if ($ARGV[0]=~"x") {
 $brute = $brute. "!\"\$%&/()=?-.:~\\*'-_:.;,";}
if ($ARGV[0]=~"lu") {
 $brute = $brute. "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";}
if ($ARGV[0]=~"ln") {
 $brute = $brute. "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";}
if ($ARGV[0]=~"un") {
 $brute = $brute. "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";}
if ($ARGV[0]=~"all") {
 $brute = $brute. "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!\"\$%&/()~=?-.:\\*'-_:.;,1234567890";}

if (! $ARGV[0]) {
usage();
exit(1);
}
if (! $ARGV[1]) {
usage();
exit(1);
}
if (! $ARGV[2]) {
usage();
exit(1);
}
if (! $ARGV[3]) {
usage();
exit(1);
}

if ($ARGV[3]) { 
    if (length($ARGV[3]) != 32) {
    print "MD5 Is Not Valid\n";
    sleep(1);
    system('clear');
    exit(1);
    }
}

if ($ARGV[0]=~"all") { 
print "Starting to Crack '$ARGV[3]'...\n";
sleep(2);
}else{
print "Starting to Crack '$ARGV[3]'...\n";
sleep(2);
}

for (my $bfv=$ARGV[1];$bfv<=$ARGV[2];$bfv++){
 crack ($bfv);
}

sub usage{
system('clear');
print '

████████╗██╗    ██╗███████╗███╗   ██╗████████╗██╗   ██╗ ██████╗ ███╗   ██╗███████╗\'s MD5 BRUTEFORCER
╚══██╔══╝██║    ██║██╔════╝████╗  ██║╚══██╔══╝╚██╗ ██╔╝██╔═══██╗████╗  ██║██╔════╝
   ██║   ██║ █╗ ██║█████╗  ██╔██╗ ██║   ██║    ╚████╔╝ ██║   ██║██╔██╗ ██║█████╗  
   ██║   ██║███╗██║██╔══╝  ██║╚██╗██║   ██║     ╚██╔╝  ██║   ██║██║╚██╗██║██╔══╝  
   ██║   ╚███╔███╔╝███████╗██║ ╚████║   ██║      ██║   ╚██████╔╝██║ ╚████║███████╗
   ╚═╝    ╚══╝╚══╝ ╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝   ╚═╝      ╚═╝    ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═══╝╚══════╝
';

print "\nUsage: perl $0 (brute_char) MIN_CHAR MAX_CHAR MD5 (options)" . "\n";
print "Ex) perl $0 all 1 5 865c0c0b4ab0e063e5caa3387c1a8741" . "\n";
print "brute_char // options;
all |   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!\"\$%&/()~=?-.:\\*'-_:.;,1234567890
-
l   |   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
-
u   |   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
-
n   |   1234567890
-
x   |   !\"\$%&/()=?-.:~\\*'-_:.;,
-
lu  |   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
-
ln  |   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890
-
un  |   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890
---
new |   Generates MD5 Hash
-
v   |   Verbose (print output)
";
}

sub crack{
 $CharSet = shift;
 @RawString = ();
 for (my $i =0;$i<$CharSet;$i++){ $RawString[i] = 0;}
 $Start = gettimeofday();
 do{
  for (my $i =0;$i<$CharSet;$i++){
   if ($RawString[$i] > length($brute)-1){
    if ($i==$CharSet-1){
    print "Bruteforce finished, no results with $CharSet charachters. \n";
    $count=0;
    return false;
   }
   $RawString[$i+1]++;
   $RawString[$i]=0;
   }
  }

   $ret = "";
   for (my $i =0;$i<$CharSet;$i++){ $ret = $ret . substr($brute,$RawString[$i],1);}
   $hash = md5_hex($ret);
   $count++;
   $Stop = gettimeofday();
   if ($Stop-$Start>$speed){
    $count = int($count/$speed);
    $count=0;
    $Start = gettimeofday();
}

if ($ARGV[4] =~ 'v') { 
print "$ARGV[3] != $hash ($ret)\n";
}

   if ($ARGV[3] eq $hash){
    print "\n[+] MD5 Cracked! => $ret\n";
    exit(1);
   }
  $RawString[0]++;
 }while($RawString[$CharSet-1]<length($brute));
}
```

I wonder about the significance of the date field in the comments at the top.  The MD5 algorithm was first published in 1992, and of course Perl 5 wasn't even released until 1994.  Possibly the author's birthdate?  His contact info is available (though I've removed it from the translated code posted here; you'll have to translate it yourself to obtain it).

A Google search on the date doesn't turn up anything that might be applicable, so I guess one would have to ask the author to unravel that part of the mystery.